# NODEMCU DOCKER marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build "Not a git repository" fatal error in WINDOWS 10

Tags: docker, nodemcu

I downloaded master firmware and put it under my user directory and i assign all permissions also to Eveyone.

After i launched this command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v //c/Users/S227233/nodemcu-firmware-master:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build build
```

But i had this:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /opt/nodemcu-firmware)
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

I also tryied this command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v //c/Users/S227233/nodemcu-firmware-master:/opt/nodemcu-firmware --env GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1 marcelstoer/nodemcu-build build
```

But i had this othe one:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have problems also with LFS images:

```
docker run -it -v //c/Users/S227233/nodemcu-firmware-master:/opt/nodemcu-firmware -v //d/_PERSONALE/_NODE_MCU/_NUOVO_CODICE_CON_LFS --env GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1 marcelstoer/nodemcu-build lfs-image
```

> Error: No cross compiler found. You need to build the firmeware first.

P.S.
Note: i use a company proxy...but i don't know if it is important because anyway docker works.

This is my nodemcu-firmware-master dir list:

```
01/15/2019 04:59 PM

.
01/15/2019 04:59 PM ..
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 860 .gdbinit
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 4,200 .gdbinitlua
01/15/2019 03:56 PM .github
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 175 .gitignore
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 228 .gitmodules
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 879 .travis.yml
01/15/2019 03:56 PM app
01/15/2019 03:56 PM bin
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 9,640 CONTRIBUTING.md
01/15/2019 03:56 PM docs
01/15/2019 03:56 PM ld
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 1,087 LICENSE
01/15/2019 03:09 PM local
01/15/2019 03:56 PM lua_examples
01/15/2019 03:09 PM lua_modules
01/15/2019 04:39 PM 12,771 Makefile
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 3,803 mkdocs.yml
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 5,167 README.md
12/07/2018 10:47 PM 312 rtd-requirements.txt
01/15/2019 03:09 PM sdk-overrides
01/15/2019 03:56 PM tools
```

Thanks.

Comment: The second issue is to be expected as the cross compilers are built during the initial firmware build. The error "You need to build the firmeware first." is accurate.

Comment: What happens if you go to `\Users\S227233\nodemcu-firmware-master` with the Windows command prompt (or however it is called) and run `git status`?

Comment: C:\Users\S227233\nodemcu-firmware-master>git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: I generally use git from Eclipse and not CLI...so i don't know if it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest comment just confirmed my suspicion. I don't know how you arrived at that folder but it really isn't a proper clone of the firmware repository.

Follow https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build#clone-the-nodemcu-firmware-repository and all will be ok.

`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.git`

Comment: Thanks. Resolving git proxy problems and using git to clone your build now starts but i have other timeout problems now. Perhaps it is better i try without proxy using my smartphone.

Comment: I have this error: wget -https://github.com/jmattsson/esp-toolchains/releases/download/linux-x86_64-20181106.0/toolchain-esp8266-linux-x86_64-20181106.0.tar.xz ...
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.118.3|:443... failed: Connection timed out.